# Calling the main method of another class

Tags: java

I am trying to call the main method of a function in another code.

The example from the command line I am trying to reproduce is:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -testFile jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv
```

from [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a)

In my code, I wrote:

```
String[] args = {"-loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz", 
        "-testFile jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv"};
CRFClassifier.main(args);
```

but when I try to execute this code, I get the following error:

```
Unknown property |loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz|
Unknown property |testFile jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv|
```

How can I call the main function from my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every part of the command line, after the class name, is a separate argument. So the code should be

```
String[] args = {"-loadClassifier", "ner-model.ser.gz", "-testFile", "jane-austen-emma-ch2.tsv"};
```